# Are the quotient groups in a composition sequence necessarily subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

Does there exist a finite group G and a normal subgroup N of G so that G/N is a simple group and G/N is not isomorphic to any subgroup of G ?

Comment: Why do you add the requirement $G/N$ simple?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat otherwise there are easy counter examples.

Comment: If $N$ is required to be simple instead of $G/N$, then the quaternion group of order 8 is a nice counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the perfect group $\operatorname{SL}(2,5)$ of order 120 is one. By Cauchy's theorem you won't find an example with $G/N$ abelian, so this is more or less the typical example. You want a non-split extension, and you probably want $N$ to be small to avoid coincidentally containing $G/N$. A good way to do this are the non-simple quasi-simple groups.

If $G/Z(G)$ is non-abelian simple, and $H \leq G$ is such that $H \cong G/Z(G)$, then $H \cap Z(G) \leq Z(H) = 1$, so we get a semi-direct product of $H$ and $Z(G)$, but such a semi-direct product is direct since $Z(G)$ is central, hence $G \cong G/Z(G) \times Z(G)$.

All we need then is for $Z(G) \leq [G,G]$, that is, for $G$ to be perfect, so that $G$ is quasi-simple.

There are examples that are not quasi-simple. It'd be nice to see a proof that they all have a (non-simple) quasi-simple subquotient, so that this example really is “typical.”

Comment: I guess $SL(4,3)$ gives an example with both $N$ and $G/N$ simple. Is there any example with both $N$ and $G/N$ non-abelian simple?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Correct. The answer to your question is no, but I'm not 100% on whether $N$ has to have abelian composition factors. If both $G/N$ and $N$ are non-abelian simple, then $G \cong G/N \times N$. Let me know if you want the proof (not hard, but it does use the CFSG, at least Schreier's conjecture).

Comment: Actually quasi-simples are only one kind of example. A6 N 3^6 (the non-split extension of A6 by a 3-dimensional GF(9) module; perfect of order 262440) is an example that contains no non-simple quasi-simple subquotients. I think quasi-simples are still good examples, but they aren't the whole story at all.